# Optimize member function selection at runtime on CPU/GPU

Tags: c++, gpgpu, arrayfire, sycl

I have the following piece of code that needs to optimized (and be later ported to the GPU through SYCL or ArrayFire):

```
struct Item {
    float value;
    int f;
    float Func(float);
    float Func1(float);
    float Func2(float);
    float Func3(float);
};

float Item::Func(float v) {
    value = v;
    switch(f) {
        case 1: return Func1(v);
        case 2: return Func2(v);
        case 3: return Func3(v);
    }
    return Func1(v);
}

std::vector<Item> items;
```

AFAIK, on GPUs the function pointer approach is not suitable.

Is there a more performant approach on CPUs and/or GPUs than this one?

Comment: Impossible to give a useful answer without seeing what these functions do and what they have in common.

Comment: Would be more readable to use a `default: return Func1`.

Comment: What is the problem with the approach on GPUs? Does not compile? Bad performance?

Comment: @Sebastian - I have not implemented it, yet. I just wanted to be sure there are no other better, more efficient approaches.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - The functions are all mathematical expressions, with no loops and no branches.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - From some compilers I get a warning for a missing return value if I add the default switch option and I remove the final return. I could keep both, of course.

Comment: Rather than passing an int and using a switch, you can pass a function pointer instead. I don't know if that is more "GPU" friendly. Are all items getting different `f` ? Is there a pattern ?

Comment: Not sure about SYCL, Cuda started accepting function pointers to kernels as parameters from host side quite early (Cuda 3.2, Compute Capability 2.x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blog post about how to implement an alternative to function pointers using SYCL [on this website](https://codeplay.com/portal/blogs/2019/09/24/alternatives-to-cpp-function-pointers-in-sycl-using-function-objects.html). The solution uses the template feature and function objects instead. I believe the history of this is that most hardware doesn't support jumping to computed addresses.